# how to filter an array based on dynamic values in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

i want to filter the given below array on the basis of dynamic values (name and section).

```
var allResponse = [
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "class": "8",
  "section": "A",
},
{
  "name": "DEF",
  "class": "7",
  "section": "B",
},
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "class": "8",
  "section": "D",
},
]
```

These values of **name and section**, i'm getting on Click of check box.
On basis of these value , i want to filter this given array **allResponse** .
Values can be multiple like:
Filter the array where **name is ABC and section is A and D**,

Like after getting value i tried to create an object to filter like given below to filter iteratively. But not able to do it

```
var filterLiterals= [{"name": "ABC"},{"section": "A"},{"section": "D"}];
or
var filterLiterals= ["ABC","A","D"];
```

So result should be

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "class": "8",
  "section": "A",
},
```

I'm confused which approach should follow to get the result.

I tried it by using || and && operator but not able to get the result what i want.

Could anybody please suggest me to suitable and proper approach to filter this array. I'm not able to do it.

Is it possible to filter in this way in javascript in any way...?

Comment: Please _show_ what you tried. [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) lets you specify arbitrarily complex code as long as you return `true` or `false`, so what did you actually write that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will accept the name and an array of section. Inside the function use `filter` and in the call back function return those object whose name matches and the `section` is included in the array of section passed to the function

```js
var allResponse = [{
    "name": "ABC",
    "class": "8",
    "section": "A",
  },
  {
    "name": "DEF",
    "class": "7",
    "section": "B",
  },
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "class": "8",
    "section": "D",
  }
]

function filterArray(name, sectionArray) {
  return allResponse.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.name = name && sectionArray.includes(elem.section)
  })
};

console.log(filterArray('ABC', ['A', 'D']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly you want to filter your data based on what you clicked.

```js
var allResponse = [
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "class": "8",
  "section": "A",
},
{
  "name": "DEF",
  "class": "7",
  "section": "B",
},
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "class": "8",
  "section": "D",
},
];

var clickedValue = "ABC";

var filteredResponse = allResponse.filter( function(response) {
   return response.name === clickedValue
});

console.log(filteredResponse);
```

I think this should resolve your filtering problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, I need to find elements satisfying below,

name: ABC
section: A or D

```js
var allResponse = [
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "class": "8",
        "section": "A",
    },
    {
        "name": "DEF",
        "class": "7",
        "section": "B",
    },
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "class": "8",
        "section": "D",
    },  
];

var filterLiterals = [
    {"name": "ABC"},
    {"section": "A"},
    {"section": "D"}
];

const parsed = filterLiterals.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    if (typeof acc[key] === 'undefined')
        acc[key] = [obj[key]];
    else 
        acc[key].push(obj[key]);
    return acc;
}, {});

//console.log("parsed: ", parsed);

var answer = allResponse.filter(obj => {
    let flag = true;
    for (const key of Object.keys(parsed)) {
        if (!parsed[key].includes(obj[key])) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
});

console.log(answer);
```

Run this!